# Application of Doob's Optional Stopping Time Theorem on new stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider a random walk on a line starting at 0. On each step the probability of moving in either direction (right or left) is 1/2. There are two particular points on the line -a, and b. If $\tau$ is the hitting time of A, then $\tau$ is not bounded, and we cannot apply Doob's Theorem. However, we can apply Doob'ts Theorem to $\tau'$ = $\min(\tau, n)$. I don't understand why $\min(\tau, n)$ is necessarily bounded.. can't the 'walker' stay between -a and b to $\infty$? so then n is $\infty$?

Comment: Here, $n$ is just a *fixed* number; $\tau$ is the time taken for the walker to hit either $a$ or $b$. So if the walker stays between $a$ and $b$ forever, it will be $\tau = \infty$; *not* $n=\infty$.

Comment: But isn't n the current step? So if it never goes to -a or b, wouldn't the current step be $\infty$? Thanks

Comment: No, no. $n$ is not the current step; it's just some constant. You could have called it $c$ or $k$ and it wouldn't make a difference.